# Magento 2 offline payment method new order status

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, payment-methods, order-status

I've created a new offline payment module using this generator http://cedcommerce.com/magento-2-module-creator/payment-module

config.xml

`....
   <order_status>pending_payment</order_status>
....`

system.xml

`<field id="order_status" translate="label" type="select" sortOrder="20" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="0">
<label>New Order Status</label><source_model>PackageName\ModuleName\Model\Config\Source\Order\Status\Pendingpayment</source_model>
 </field>`

I'want to set new order status to `pending` or `pending_payment`, but it set to processing when creating a order every time.

Answer (score -1):

first create observer into `events.xml app\code\Adamsmage\Statuschange\etc\events.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
<event name="sales_order_place_after">
    <observer name="vendor_sales_order_place_after" instance="Adamsmage\Statuschange\Observer\OrderObserver" />
</event>
</config>
```

second create Observer file at following location `app\code\Adamsmage\Statuschange\Observer\OrderObserver.php`

```
<?php
namespace Adamsmage\Statuschange\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;

class OrderObserver implements ObserverInterface
{
public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
{
    $order = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder();
    // also if you want to check condition here like only offline payment method than order status update etc....
    $order->setState("pending")->setStatus("pending");
    $order->save(); 
}
```